# Strange behavour with SqlParameter

Tags: .net, indexoutofboundsexception, sqlclient

Using .Net 4.5.2 I have the following example code...

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CONTENTHYPERLINK", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
cmd.Parameters["@contentHyperlink"].Value = "hello world";
```

The third link causes an `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception

But if I use **any** of the following (which purely changes the case of the parameter name) it works!

```
cmd.Parameters["@CONTENTHYPERLINK"].Value = "hello world";
cmd.Parameters["@contenthyperlink"].Value = "hello world";
cmd.Parameters["@contenTHYperlink"].Value = "hello world";
```

If I use **any** of the following, it **doesn't** work...

```
cmd.Parameters["@contentHyperlink"].Value = "hello world";
cmd.Parameters["@contentHYPERLINK"].Value = "hello world";
cmd.Parameters["@CONTENtHYPERLINK"].Value = "hello world";
```

(And there are are lots more examples of ones that do and don't work that I won't bother listing here.)

Why on earth does something that should be case-insensitive throw an exception on particular cases?

(I realise the solution to the problem is use one that doesn't cause an exception, but I want to know why this is happening)

---

**Update**

After changing the code to use upper-case, the exact same thing has happened on another sproc parameter...

```
cmd.Parameters["@PortalLastLogon"]  <-- Fails
cmd.Parameters["@portalLastlogon"]  <-- Fails

cmd.Parameters["@PORTALLASTLOGON"]  <-- Works
cmd.Parameters["@portallastlogon"]  <-- Works
```

This is driving me insane... if I had any hair left to pull out, I'd be as bald as I already am.

Can **anybody** explain what on earth is going on?!

I have a piece of software with over 2400 sproc parameters... I cannot afford the time update them all!

Comment: Does that happen in a new empty project?  For me all the examples work as expected in 4.5.2

Comment: @Alex - I'm just trying something similar (an earlier version of the project, where this code has worked for over 10 years without issue)

Comment: @Alex - sigh... it's working :-(  ok, need to figure out what's going on

Comment: Not trying to take the wind off your sail, but you do realize that the three lines of code you started your question with can be written in a single line, like this: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@CONTENTHYPERLINK", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "hello world";`, right?

Comment: @Zohar - thanks for the advice, but it doesn't help me in the slightest for this particular issue.  The code was originally all written using designers, so all the code is spread between `InitializeComponent()` and methods

Comment: Just wondering, would knowing *why* it happens help you get a better understanding on *how* to prevent it, other than rewriting your existing code? I know what it's like to work on legacy code, I've recently had to make changes to code I've written 9 years ago, on vb.net (didn't use that language for over 6 years). I know it's a pain, but at least, if you are going to have to rewrite, you can make the next maintenance easier...

Comment: Sorry @Zohar, but I'm not sure exactly what you're asking?  If I knew why it was happening, I could make it not happen

Comment: Perhaps, but I'll bet you will have to re-write at least some of the code to make it not happen... What I'm saying is, if you are going to rewrite anyway, why not write it better?

Comment: @Zohar, I've literally just figured it out.  We've just added new language functionality to the system... and it's open happening when we're set to one of the different language cultures.  At least I know **why** it's happening - now I have to figure out **how** to fix it ;-)

Comment: Well, that's great news! Hope you can do that without too much effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that the reason this is happening is our recent introduction of code for language culture handling.

Within the `[Global].Application_BeginRequest` part of my ASP.Net web application, I am setting the following...

```
var culture = new Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureCode);
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

The particular language I'm working with is Welsh (code `cy`)... and there must be something very strange within the case-insensitive checking for this culture which means it's not matching.

The moment I put it back to English, the problem disappears.

At this time I don't have an answer as to *how* I'm going to fix the issue without updating every single sproc call to upper-case... but at least I have a reason *why* it's failing.

---

Delving into [the .Net source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/EntityClient/DbParameterCollectionHelper.cs,66c55b6248de807b) shows that the [`IndexOf`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/EntityClient/DbParameterCollectionHelper.cs,da046d94d9a7db65,references) is using both [`EntityUtil.SrcCompare`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Common/EntityUtil.cs,127ce2c898416275,references) which does a straight `==` comparison... but also [`EntityUtil.DstCompare`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Common/EntityUtil.cs,66c55b6248de807b) which does a culture based `Compare`.

So at least I have proof that the culture is having an effect.

---

The following will demonstrate the issue (using the same CompareOptions as the EntityUtil.DstCompare)...

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
var enResult = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare("lL", "LL",
    CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType | CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
// enResult == 0 as expected

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("cy");
var cyResult = System.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare("lL", "LL",
    CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType | CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
// cyResult == -1
```

As I need the system to be running under the culture, I have no choice but to write a script to update all `Parameters[xxx]` to match the case of the definition exactly.

Comment: Maybe the SqlParametersCollection uses the current culture. If that was the case it would be disgusting.

Comment: @usr - if you delve into [the .Net source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/EntityClient/DbParameterCollectionHelper.cs,66c55b6248de807b) you'll see that the `IndexOf` is using both [`EntityUtil.SrcCompare`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Common/EntityUtil.cs,127ce2c898416275,references) which does a straight `==` comparison... but also [`EntityUtil.DstCompare`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Common/EntityUtil.cs,66c55b6248de807b) which does a culture based `Compare`. Sigh